# How to change two place buttons?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an Android application which is basically a game. In one of the Activities there are a few buttons, and I wanted that when one event occurred (it could even be the trigger of another button) two buttons changed position in the layout. I researched the documentation of the Transition class to see if it was possible to use an animation to make this switch, but I really wanted something with a non-existent delay.

NOTE: Just changing the appearance of the buttons is not an option for me, since each of these buttons has different functions within the application and I need to keep them.

Answer (score 0):

You can have four buttons two on each layout. Then you make two gone. Then you tie two each to same function trigger and when a button is pressed you make the first layout gone and show the second layout which is a 2nd button on top of 1st. NB the first layout should have 1st button on top and 2nd button below it

Comment: The problem is that I need to do this switch with ten buttons between them

Comment: I get you. I will try a more efficient one

Comment: I thought of something like creating an xml file for each button and calling it in the main layout by my Java logic, but I do not know if I use a Relative Layout, Frame Layout or what are the methods needed to do this "insert". Thanks for the help

Comment: Use Linearlayout and create each button view using this. LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.myfile, null);

Comment: Wait, how do I reference my xml file of the button to the LinearLayout id in this code line?

Comment: Create an xml layout with your preferred name. Use Linearlayout for the parent view and define your button in that xml layout. Open your java code and call the layout with  this: LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.myfile, null);

Answer (score 0):

```
        package com.dovoh.buttonpositionchange;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        Button btnFirst, btnSecond;

        final static String ONE= "BUTTON ONE";
        final static String TWO= "BUTTON TWO";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            //buttons
            btnFirst = findViewById(R.id.first);
            btnSecond= findViewById(R.id.second);



            btnFirst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                  if(btnFirst.getText().equals(ONE)){
                     TwoFuction(view);
                  }
                  else if(btnFirst.getText().equals(TWO)){
                      OneFuction(view);
                  }

                  else Default(view);
                }
            });

            btnSecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(btnSecond.getText().equals(TWO)){
                        OneFuction(view);
                    }
                    else if(btnSecond.getText().equals(ONE)){
                        OneFuction(view);
                    }

                    else Default(view);
                }
            });


        }
        public void Default(View view){
            btnFirst.setText(ONE);
            btnSecond.setText(TWO);
        }

        public void OneFuction(View view){
            btnFirst.setText(ONE);
            btnSecond.setText(TWO);
        }

        public void TwoFuction(View view){
            btnSecond.setText(ONE);
            btnFirst.setText(TWO);
        }
    }


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.dovoh.buttonpositionchange.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:text="BUTTON ONE"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/second"
            android:text="BUTTON TWO"
            android:layout_below="@+id/first"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This way I would need to create 100 different layouts for all 100 possibilities that I would have alternating the 10 buttons of my Activity. But thanks for the idea, if I have no other alternative, I'll try to do it this way and hope not to overload the application